# Python - break isn't working?

Tags: python

Could someone please help me to understand why the program doesn't output 'Well done!' after I input 1? Thank you.

```
while True:
    o=input("Enter 1:")
    if o==1:
        break
print("Well done!")
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're using python3.x.

On python3.x, `input` *always* returns an instance of `str`, so `o` will never equal the `1` since you're comparing different types (`str` and `int`).